# Patch value of dropdown back to sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

I populated a dropdown list with values from a column in a collection. I am now trying to patch the selected value back to my sharepoint list and I'm getting errors.

The formula in the Items property of my dropdown is `colBudgetFilter.LineItem`

The Patch formula I'm trying to use is...

```
Patch(
    Vouchers,
    LookUp(Vouchers, ID=gal_FirstApprover_VoucherDetails.Selected.ID),
    {
        LineItem: lbl_FirstApprover_LineItemDetail.Selected.Value
    }
);
```

The error I'm getting is *The type of this argument 'LineItem' does not match the expected type 'Text'. Found type 'Error'.*

I've worked with dropdowns before and they have worked just fine like this, but I've never tried to do the same using a collection as the dropdown data source.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the items property use `Distinct(colBudgetFilter,LineItem)` instead of `colBudgetFilter.LineItem`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your formula should reference the field in the collection as LineItem instead of Value

```
Patch(
        Vouchers,
        LookUp(Vouchers, ID=gal_FirstApprover_VoucherDetails.Selected.ID),
        {
            LineItem: lbl_FirstApprover_LineItemDetail.Selected.LineItem
        }
    );
```